# Meaning of "Can you come through?"

Tags: lyrics

Here are some lyrics from the song "comethru" by Jeremy Zucker

> I might lose my mind
>   Waking when the sun's down
>   Riding all these highs
>   Waiting for the comedown
>   Walk these streets with me
>   I'm doing decently
>   Just glad that I can breathe, yeah
>
> I'm trying to realize
>   It's alright to not be fine on your own
>
> Now I'm shaking, drinking all this coffee
>   These last few weeks have been exhausting
>   I'm lost in my imagination
>   And there's one thing that I need from you
>   Can you come through, through
>   Through, yeah
>   And there's one thing that I need from you
>   Can you come through?

What's the precise meaning of 'Can you come through?' in this song?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Sorry, but song lyrics are usually considered off-topic as they have different requirements such as rhyme and scansion.

Comment: You can project any meaning of *[come through](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-through)* onto the lyric you like, but only the lyricist would know whether a specific interpretation is intended. We accord a wide degree of [artistic license](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/artistic+license) to creative works like song lyrics, so the words do not necessarily meaning anything in particular—they might have been selected simply for being evocative, or fitting the rhythm. I would try a lyrics site like Genius.com or SongMeanings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm sorry if my question was not appropriate in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of song lyrics, as with any artistic medium, that they are **always** subject to artistic interpretation, without consulting with the original artist we can only ever hope to provide our own subjective interpretation of what they meant.

That said, given that the line in question

> "*Can you come through, through Through, yeah*"

was preceded by

> *"And there's one thing I need from you"*

I'd interpret the meaning of "come through" in this context to mean, "come through [for me]". We don't know exactly what the artist is requesting, but the phrase ["come through"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20through) is a phrasal verb which generally means "fulfill some task". We can't know *exactly* what the singer is requesting but judging by the following line

> "*I'm trying to realize It's alright to not be fine on your own*"

I suspect that "come through" in this case means "be there for me"

But again, this is all just conjecture